Converting SQLite DB database helper to sqflite format to use on web
Here is my database helper code using sqflite flutter library that works on Android,iOS and MacOS.But I want my app to work on web as well, what is the best way to covert this piece of code to web ?
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:excel/excel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:frag_store/features/controllers/compounds/create_compound_controller.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static Future<Database> database() async {
    return openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'FragStore.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) async {
        await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE Users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, firstName TEXT, lastName TEXT, gender TEXT, email TEXT, phoneNumber TEXT, password TEXT)",
        );
        
        await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE VendorLogs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, company TEXT, date TEXT, item TEXT, price TEXT, qty TEXT, unit TEXT, notes TEXT)",
        );
        await db.execute('''
  CREATE TABLE Compound (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    ingredientsname TEXT,
    ingredient
sqty TEXT,
    ingredientsunit TEXT,
    qty TEXT, 
    unit TEXT, 
    notes TEXT, 
    specification TEXT, 
    usage TEXT, 
    tags TEXT, 
    fragrancenotes TEXT,
    price REAL -- Add price field
  )
''');

        await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE Vendors(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, phone TEXT, country TEXT, location TEXT, address TEXT, category TEXT, tags TEXT)",
        );
        await db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE Ingredients(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, price TEXT, qty TEXT, unit TEXT, notes TEXT, specification TEXT, usage TEXT, tags TEXT, fragrancenotes TEXT)",
        );
        await db.execute('''
    CREATE TRIGGER update_compound_price
    AFTER UPDATE OF price ON Ingredients
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Compound
        SET price = (
            SELECT SUM(CAST(Ingredients.price AS REAL) * Ingredients.qty)
            FROM Compound c
            JOIN Ingredients ON c.ingredientsname = Ingredients.name
        )
        WHERE Compound.name IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT c.name
            FROM Compound c
            JOIN Ingredients ON c.ingredientsname = Ingredients.name
        );
    END;
''');


        await db.execute('''
CREATE TABLE FragranceNotes (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  note TEXT
)
''');

        await db.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Tags (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  tag TEXT
)
''');

// Add default values to FragranceNotes table
//         await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ("Woody")');
//         await db
//             .rawInsert('INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ("Peaceful")');
//         await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ("Bold")');

// // Add default values to Tags table
//         await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO Tags(tag) VALUES ("Light")');
//         await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO Tags(tag) VALUES ("Classy")');
//         await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO Tags(tag) VALUES ("Scented")');
//         // Adding Vendor table
      },
      version: 1,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> insertIngredient(Map<String, dynamic> ingredient) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    await db.insert(
      'Ingredients', // Assuming the table name is Ingredients
      ingredient,
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }

  static Future<bool> isIngredient(String name) async {
    final db = await database();
    final result =
        await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Ingredients WHERE name = ?", [name]);
    return result.isNotEmpty;
  }

  // Method to fetch data of an ingredient
  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getIngredientData(String name) async {
    final db = await database();
    final result =
        await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Ingredients WHERE name = ?", [name]);
    return result.isNotEmpty ? result.first : {};
  }

  static Future<void> updateIngredient(
      String name,
      String price,
      String qty,
      String notes,
      String specification,
      String usage,
      List<String> tags,
      List<String> fragranceNotes) async {
    try {
      // Open the database
      Database db = await openDatabase('FragStore.db');

      // Perform the update operation
      await db.update(
        'Ingredients',
        {
          'price': price,
          'qty': qty,
          'notes': notes,
          'specification': specification,
          'usage': usage,
          'tags':
              tags.join(', '), // Convert List<String> to comma-separated string
          'fragrancenotes': fragranceNotes
              .join(', '), // Convert List<String> to comma-separated string
        },
        where: 'name = ?',
        whereArgs: [name],
      );

      // Close the database
      await db.close();
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to update ingredient: $e');
    }
  }

  static Future<void> updateCompound(
      String name,
      String price,
      String qty,
      String notes,
      String specification,
      String usage,
      List<String> tags,
      List<String> fragranceNotes) async {
    try {
      // Open the database
      Database db = await openDatabase('FragStore.db');

      // Perform the update operation
      await db.update(
        'Compound',
        {
          'price': price,
          'qty': qty,
          'notes': notes,
          'specification': specification,
          'usage': usage,
          'tags':
              tags.join(', '), // Convert List<String> to comma-separated string
          'fragrancenotes': fragranceNotes
              .join(', '), // Convert List<String> to comma-separated string
        },
        where: 'name = ?',
        whereArgs: [name],
      );

      // Close the database
      await db.close();
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to update compound: $e');
    }
  }

  static Future<List<String>> fetchFragranceNotes() async {
    final Database db = await database();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('FragranceNotes');
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return maps[i]['note'];
    });
  }

  static Future<void> insertTag(String tag) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    await db.insert('Tags', {'tag': tag});
  }

  static Future<void> insertFragranceNote(String note) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    await db.insert('FragranceNotes', {'note': note});
  }

  static Future<List<String>> fetchTags() async {
    final Database db = await database();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('Tags');
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return maps[i]['tag'];
    });
  }
  static Future<List<String>> fetchIngredients() async {
    final Database db = await database();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> ingredients = await db.query('Ingredients');
    return List.generate(ingredients.length, (i) {
      return ingredients[i]['name'];
    });
  }
  static Future<List<String>> fetchCompounds() async {
    final Database db = await database();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> compound = await db.query('Compound');
    return List.generate(compound.length, (i) {
      return compound[i]['name'];
    });
  }

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchQuantityAndUnit(
      String selectedTable, TextEditingController selectedItem) async {
    Database db = await database();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = await db.query(
      selectedTable,
      where: 'name = ?',
      whereArgs: [selectedItem.text],
    );
    if (result.isNotEmpty) {
      // If a record is found, return the quantity and unit
      return {'quantity': result.first['qty'], 'unit': result.first['unit']};
    } else {
      // If no record is found, return default values
      return {
        'quantity': 0,
        'unit':
            'default_unit' // You can replace 'default_unit' with your desired default unit
      };
    }
  }

  static Future<void> updateQuantityAndUnit(String selectedTable,
      String selectedItem, int newQuantity, String newUnit) async {
    Database db = await database();
    await db.update(
      selectedTable,
      {'qty': newQuantity, 'unit': newUnit},
      where: 'name = ?',
      whereArgs: [selectedItem],
    );
  }

  // Method to fetch data of a compound
  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getCompoundData(String name) async {
    final db = await database();
    final result =
        await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Compound WHERE name = ?", [name]);
    return result.isNotEmpty ? result.first : {};
    
  }

  // Method to insert compound data into the database
  static Future<void> insertCompoundEntry(
      Map<String, dynamic> compoundData) async {
    final db = await database();
    await db.insert('Compound', compoundData);
  }

  static Future<bool> doesIngredientExist(String name) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> ingredients = await db.query(
      'Ingredients', // Assuming the table name is Ingredients
      where: 'name = ?',
      whereArgs: [name],
    );
    return ingredients.isNotEmpty;
  }

  static Future<bool> doesCompoundExist(String name) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> compound = await db.query(
      'Compound', // Assuming the table name is Ingredients
      where: 'name = ?',
      whereArgs: [name],
    );
    return compound.isNotEmpty;
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getAllCompounds() async {
    final Database db = await database();
    return await db.query('Compound');
  }

  static Future<bool> doesVendorExist(String name) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> vendors = await db.query(
      'Vendors',
      where: 'name = ?',
      whereArgs: [name],
    );
    return vendors.isNotEmpty;
  }

  static Future<void> insertUser(Map<String, dynamic> user) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    await db.insert(
      'Users',
      user,
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> insertVendorLog(Map<String, dynamic> log) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    await db.insert(
      'VendorLogs',
      log,
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> deleteUserByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
    final db = await database();
    await db.delete(
      'Users',
      where: 'phoneNumber = ?',
      whereArgs: [phoneNumber],
    );
  }

  static Future<void> deleteCompound(String compoundName) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    await db.delete(
      'Compound',
      where: 'name = ?',
      whereArgs: [compoundName],
    );
  }

  static Future<void> deleteIngredient(String ingredientName) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    await db.delete(
      'Ingredients',
      where: 'name = ?',
      whereArgs: [ingredientName],
    );
  }

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getUserByPhoneAndPassword(
      String phoneNumber, String password) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> users = await db.query(
      'Users',
      where: 'phoneNumber = ? AND password = ?',
      whereArgs: [phoneNumber, password],
    );
    if (users.isNotEmpty) {
      return users.first;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  static Future<bool> userExistsWithPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> users = await db.query(
      'Users',
      where: 'phoneNumber = ?',
      whereArgs: [phoneNumber],
    );
    return users.isNotEmpty;
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getAllUsers() async {
    final Database db = await database();
    return await db.query('Users');
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getAllIngredients() async {
    final Database db = await database();
    return await db.query('Ingredients');
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getAllCompanyLogs() async {
    final Database db = await database();
    return await db.query('VendorLogs');
  }

  static Future<void> exportUsersToExcel() async {
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> users = await getAllUsers();
    final documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = '${documentsDirectory.path}/Users.xlsx';

    final file = File(path);
    if (await file.exists()) {
      await file.delete();
    }

    final excel = Excel.createExcel();
    final sheet = excel['Sheet1'];
    sheet.appendRow([
      'id',
      'firstName',
      'lastName',
      'gender',
      'email',
      'phoneNumber',
      'password'
    ]);

    for (final user in users) {
      sheet.appendRow([
        user['id'],
        user['firstName'],
        user['lastName'],
        user['gender'],
        user['email'],
        user['phoneNumber'],
        user['password'],
      ]);
    }

    final fileBytes = excel.encode();
    await file.writeAsBytes(fileBytes!);
    print('Excel file saved to: $path');
  }

  static Future<void> insertVendor(Map<String, dynamic> vendor) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    await db.insert(
      'Vendors', // Assuming the table name is Vendors
      vendor,
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getVendorLogs() async {
    final Database db = await database();
    return await db.query('VendorLogs');
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getVendorLogsByCompany(
      String company) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    return await db.query(
      'VendorLogs',
      where: 'company = ?',
      whereArgs: [company],
    );
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>
      getAggregatedVendorLogsByCompanyAndTenure(
          String company, String tenure) async {
    final Database db = await database();
    String groupByClause;
    List<dynamic> whereArgs = [company];
    String tenureColumn;

    if (tenure == 'Monthly') {
      groupByClause = "item, strftime('%Y-%m', date)";
      tenureColumn = "strftime('%Y-%m', date) AS tenure";
    } else if (tenure == 'Yearly') {
      groupByClause = "item, strftime('%Y', date)";
      tenureColumn = "strftime('%Y', date) AS tenure";
    } else {
      throw ArgumentError('Invalid tenure: $tenure');
    }

    return await db.query(
      'VendorLogs',
      columns: [
        'company',
        'item',
        'unit',
        'SUM(price) AS totalPrice',
        'SUM(qty) AS totalQuantity',
        tenureColumn
      ],
      where: 'company = ?',
      whereArgs: whereArgs,
      groupBy: groupByClause,
      orderBy: 'date DESC',
    );
  }

  static Future<void> exportVendorLogsToExcel() async {
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> logs = await getVendorLogs();
    final documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = '${documentsDirectory.path}/VendorLogs.xlsx';

    final file = File(path);
    if (await file.exists()) {
      await file.delete();
    }

    final excel = Excel.createExcel();
    final sheet = excel['Sheet1'];

    sheet.appendRow([
      'id',
      'company',
      'date',
      'item',
      'price',
      'qty',
      'unit',
      'notes',
    ]);

    for (final log in logs) {
      sheet.appendRow([
        log['id'],
        log['company'],
        log['date'],
        log['item'],
        log['price'],
        log['qty'],
        log['unit'],
        log['notes'],
      ]);
    }

    final fileBytes = excel.encode();
    await file.writeAsBytes(fileBytes!);
    print('Excel file saved to: $path');
  }

  static Future<void> insertDummyCompounds() async {
    final Database db = await database();
    await db.transaction((txn) async {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        await txn.insert(
          'Compounds',
          {'name': 'Compound $i', 'stockAvailable': 10},
        );
      }
    });
  }
}

I modified my main.dart to look like this :-
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:frag_store/app.dart';
import 'package:frag_store/features/screens/login/login.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi_web/sqflite_ffi_web.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

void main() {
  // Initialize FFI
  if (kIsWeb) {
    // Some web specific code there

databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfiWeb;  
}

  runApp(App());
}


but if I try
// Add default values to Fragran
ceNotes table
//         await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ("Woody")');
//         await db
//             .rawInsert('INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ("Peaceful")');
//         await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ("Bold")');

// // Add default values to Tags table
//         await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO Tags(tag) VALUES ("Light")');
//         await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO Tags(tag) VALUES ("Classy")');
//         await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO Tags(tag) VALUES ("Scented")');
//         // Adding Vendor table using

the database helper
it gives an error :-
error SqfliteFfiException(sqlite_error: 1, , SqliteException(1): while executing, no such column: Woody, SQL logic error (code 1)
  Causing statement: INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ("Woody"), parameters: }) DatabaseException(SqliteException(1): while executing, no such
  column: Woody, SQL logic error (code 1)
  Causing statement: INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ("Woody"), parameters: ) sql 'INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ("Woody")'
  {details: {database: {path: /FragStore.db, id: 1, readOnly: false, singleInstance: true}}} during open, closing.... 

Although this piece of code works for sqflite.

Woody is being considered as an identifier not a string literal as per:-

If a keyword in double quotes (ex: "key" or "glob") is used in a context where it cannot be resolved to an identifier but where a string literal is allowed, then the token is understood to be a string literal instead of an identifier. https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

You may wish to consider using single quotes instead of double quotes, as per:-

If a keyword in single quotes (ex: 'key' or 'glob') is used in a context where an identifier is allowed but where a string literal is not allowed, then the token is understood to be an identifier instead of a string literal.


i.e. a string literal is allowed and thus the string literal will be understood to be the value to use.

Consider the following demo (using an SQLite tool (Navicat)):-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FragranceNotes;
CREATE TABLE FragranceNotes (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  note TEXT
);
INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ('Woody');
INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ("Woody");


bar the DROP the code/SQl has been copied directly from the question.

The result as per the messages output by the SQLite tool:-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FragranceNotes
> OK
> Time: 0.113s


CREATE TABLE FragranceNotes (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  note TEXT
)
> OK
> Time: 0.024s


INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ('Woody')
> Affected rows: 1
> Time: 0.024s


INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ("Woody")
> no such column: Woody
> Time: 0s

i.e. The

DROP, (added just in case there was a need to rerun)
CREATE,
and 1st INSERT

all work as expected.
BUT, the second insert, using double quotes instead of single quotes for the literal value, results in the issue you have encountered, as explained.
i.e. no such column: Woody

lib/utils/database_helper.dart:80:71: Error: Expected ',' before this.
await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ('Woody')');
^^^^^

@DeepankarVarma see https://www.darttutorial.org/dart-tutorial/dart-string/  e.g. db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO FragranceNotes(note) VALUES ('Woody')"); i.e. double quotes for the string so you can code single quotes within the string.
